# What is the proper xpath query for this specific html section?

Tags: php, xpath

What is the right xpath query to get only the value: 5.3 ?

```
<span class="bla">5.3<span>/10</span></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
//span[@class="bla"]/text()
```

Comment: Depending on whether the outer span can have further text child nodes (for instance after the inner span) and if those further text child nodes should not be selected it might be necessary to add `[1]` e.g `//span[@class="bla"]/text()[1]`.